# CKEDITOR - Set Caret to end

Tags: dom, ckeditor, range, selection

I'm working a lot with positioning within CKEDITOR. 
But i still can't figure out why the following code 
sometimes doesn't work?

```
    var range = new CKEDITOR.dom.range(editor.document);
    range.moveToElementEditablePosition(element, setToEnd);
    editor.getSelection().selectRanges([range]);
```

I think that it has something to do with the element input that i'm giving. 
But i'm not sure.

Does anybody know what are the requirements for the moveToElementEditbalePosition to work?
The last time that i checked my input was a SPAN Element.

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-moveToElementEditablePosition

Or is there a more secure(cross-browser) solution?

==== edit ====

I found an error, And it's coming from the new CKEDITOR.dom.range

TypeError: b is undefined

This means that editor.document is empty, but when i look in the editor.document it's filled?

When i'm trying to set the range a second time after the error also it shows the following error: uncaught exception: DOMException: INVALID_STATE_ERR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this HTML:

```
<p><span id="test">Text</span></p>
```

And this JS:

```
var e = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
var span = e.document.getById( 'test' );
var range = e.createRange();

range.moveToElementEditablePosition( span, 1 );
range.select();
e.insertText( 'FOO' );

range.moveToElementEditablePosition( span );
range.select();
e.insertText( 'BAR' );
```

The result seems to be correct:

```
<p><span>BARTextFOO</span></p>
```

Do you have any other cases?

Comment: Your solution is shorter and cleaner. And works with the getByID code but also with my getNextNode() to find the element. 
I don't know if it had something to do with the new CKEDITOR.dom.range  version that i used. but your solution works!, as always.